react native - autolinking.json generate wrong cmakeListsPath
I am researching how to create a library for react native new architecture (bridgeless mode).
I use the cmd npx create-react-native-library@0.41.2 my-config to create a library.
After adding native code, I am able to run the code with the example project (provided by create-react-native-library)
Below is the dependencies inside autolinking.json of the example project
"dependencies": {
  "my-config": {
    "root": "...",
    "name": "...",
    "platforms": {
      "ios": {...},
      "android": {
        ...
        "cmakeListsPath": "/Users/.../my-config/android/generated/jni/CMakeLists.txt",
      }
    }
  },
},

However, when I pull the library to the actual project, the cmakeListsPath got an error. Below is the dependencies inside autolinking.json of the actual project
"dependencies": {
  "my-config": {
    "root": "...",
    "name": "...",
    "platforms": {
      "ios": {...},
      "android": {
        ...
        "cmakeListsPath": "/Users/.../my-config/android/build/generated/source/codegen/jni/CMakeLists.txt",
      }
    }
  },
},

As you can see the cmakeListsPath changed:

From: /Users/.../my-config/android/generated/jni/CMakeLists.txt
To  : /Users/.../my-config/android/build/generated/source/codegen/jni/CMakeLists.txt

The think is if I change the cmakeListsPath in my actual project to /Users/.../my-config/android/generated/jni/CMakeLists.txt, everything works again.
Therefore, I guess in the actual project, there is a config with make the cmakeListsPath point to incorrect path.
Please let me know if you know how to solve this.
Many thanks!
